# Visual Basic Parse Xml File Using XmlDocument

Tags: xml, vba, xmldocument

I have xml file with this codes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="PACKAGE_NAME" version="PROJECT_VERSION" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>PROJECT_NAME</name>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="MIN_SDK" />
    <preference name="android-versionCode" value="VERSION_CODE" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="INSTALL" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="TARGET_SDK" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="ORIENTATION" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="FULLSCREEN" />
</widget>
```

And i have this variables:

```
Dim PackageName, ProjectName, ProjectVersion, VersionCode, MinSdk, TargetSdk, InstallLocation, Orientation, FullScreen As String
```

I use this code to get ProjectName, PackageName and ProjectVersion:

```
Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load("config.xml")
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
PackageName = root.GetAttribute("id")
ProjectVersion = root.GetAttribute("version")
ProjectName = root.GetElementsByTagName("name").Item(0).InnerText
```

But i can't get this values:

```
VersionCode = VERSION_CODE
MinSdk = MIN_SDK
TargetSdk = TARGET_SDK
FullScreen = FULLSCREEN
Orientation = ORIENTATION
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? The xpaths for the required values are very basic and you should be able to code them.

Comment: @PankajJaju i edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found answer :)

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("config.xml")
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
PackageName = root.GetAttribute("id")
ProjectVersion = root.GetAttribute("version")
ProjectName = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name").Item(0).InnerText
For i = 0 To doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Count - 1
    If (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("fullscreen")) Then
        FullScreen = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    ElseIf (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("orientation")) Then
        Orientation = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    ElseIf (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("android-minSdkVersion")) Then
        MinSdk = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    ElseIf (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("android-targetSdkVersion")) Then
        TargetSdk = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    ElseIf (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("android-installLocation")) Then
        InstallLocation = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    ElseIf (doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Value.Contains("android-versionCode")) Then
        VersionCode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("preference").Item(i).Attributes.Item(1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you use xpaths to get the desired values. This will cleanup your code and it is much easier to maintain if you put the xpaths in an array and use a loop to traverse the array (scalable code)

Comment: @PankajJaju  I do not know how to use it :(

Comment: Hi Milad, I have posted sample code which uses xpath to fetch values

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, here is the sample code which you can use to get the values using xpath

```
Sub test()
    Dim objXML, arrNodes, nodesXML, i

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    With objXML
        .SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets'"
        .ValidateOnParse = True
        .Async = False
        .Load "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.xml"
    End With

    arrNodes = Array("/s:widget/s:preference[@name='android-minSdkVersion']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/s:preference[@name='android-versionCode']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/s:preference[@name='android-installLocation']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/s:preference[@name='android-targetSdkVersion']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/s:preference[@name='orientation']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/s:preference[@name='fullscreen']/@value", _
                    "/s:widget/@id", _
                    "/s:widget/@version", _
                    "/s:widget/s:name")

    For i = LBound(arrNodes) To UBound(arrNodes)
        Set nodesXML = objXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(arrNodes(i))
        MsgBox nodesXML.Text
    Next

    Set nodesXML = Nothing: Set objXML = Nothing
End Sub
```